# Retrieving post images from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

my problem is that this code below retrieve images as attachments only for first four posts. For others it retrieves only post title. And each end every post is equal and stored same way in database and in backend of a wordpress site. And it retrieves first four and image of I think 16th post.

```
    $myposts = get_posts(array(
        'category' => $_POST["kategorija"], 
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
  );
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 

$title = $post->post_title;
$date = $post->post_date;
$content = $post->post_content;
$status = $post->post_status; 

?>

    <li>
<?php
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail' );

          }
     }
     ?>
    <h2><?php echo $title; ?> </h2>
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="oglas.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="idKategorije" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="selektuj" />
      </form>

    </li>
<?php
endforeach; ?> 
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you have two arguments? Aren't you looking for all the attachments to posts in "'category' => $_POST["kategorija"]"? If so, why the second argument?

Comment: I don't understand which second argument ? This $_POST["kategorija"] is number of category (ID),  that I pass from android app.. I can't hardcode it on some particular number.. @user2197029

Comment: If you already have the posts, why do you need this$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

Comment: First I retrieve posts then in foreach loop go trough them and then for each post by post->ID I fetch args on that defined array of options. If you know the answer please tell me. @user2197029

Answer (score 0):

Well since you already get the posts in your first get_posts, I don;t see why you need another one.

This is from [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_all_attachments) in the Codex:

====

Show attachments for the current post[edit]
Do this inside The Loop (where $post->ID is available).

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' =>'any', 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
if ( $attachments ) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: But you also have used $attachments = get_posts.. ? @user2197029